# Hibernate(HQL) - how to find the unique query from many to many tables?

Tags: hibernate, hql

```
public class Menu { 
  private int menuId; 
  private String name;
  private Set<Item> items=new HashSet<Item>(); 

} 
public class Item { 
  private int itemId; 
  private String name; 
  private Set<Menu> menus=new HashSet<Menu>();
}
```

Menu's xml:

```
<class name="Menu" table="menu">
    <id name="menuId" type="java.lang.Integer" column="menuId">
        <generator class="increment"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string" column="menuName" length="100"></property>
    <set access="property" lazy="true" inverse="false" cascade="save-update"
        name="items" batch-size="10" fetch="select" table="menu_item">
        <key column="menuId" />
        <many-to-many class="Item" column="itemId" />
    </set>
```

Item's xml:

```
<class name="Item" table="item">
    <id name="itemId" type="java.lang.Integer" column="itemId">
        <generator class="increment"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string" column="itemName" length="100"></property>
    <set access="property" lazy="true" inverse="false" cascade="save-update"
        name="menus" batch-size="10" fetch="select" table="menu_item">
        <key column="itemId" />
        <many-to-many class="Menu" column="menuId" />
    </set>
</class>
```

question1:
I would like to find the menus whose items' itemIds are not 1 or 2.
For example,one menu's items' itemIds are 1,3,4.
I try to do hql like this:

```
select menu 
from Menu menu, In(menu.items) items 
where items.itemId not in (1,2)
```

But actually it will find this menu.

How can I do it?

question2:
I would like to find the menus whose item's itemIds are 1 and 2 at the same time.
I try to do hql like this:

select menu 
from Menu menu, In(menu.items) items 
where items.itemId in (1,2)

But actually it will find the menu whos itemIds are 1 or 2, not 1 and 2.
How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is **itemId** unique in the table?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Criteria query for this if it is acceptable.Following is the snippet

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Menu.class);
List<Menu> list = new ArrayList<Menu>();
dc.createAlias("items","item");
dc.add(Restrictions.and(
     Restrictions.ne("item.itemId",1),
               Restrictions.ne("item.itemId",2)));
list = hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(dc);
```

This gives you all Menus with ItemId not equal to 1 and 2.

Use the similar kind of query for other question also.Hope this helps you.
BTW I have not tested this solution.

Comment: Is there any error or it is giving invalid results? BTW can you post me the SQL it generated if it is giving invalid result? else the error msg in case of error

Answer (score 0):

I have found by myself 
1.from Menu menu where 2=(select count(menu.id) from Menu menu,In (menu.items)items where items.itemId in (1,2)) 
2.select menu2 from Menu menu2 where 3=(select count(menu.id) from Menu menu,In (menu.items) items where items.itemId in (1,2,3) and menu.menuId=menu2.menuId)